# Mass Assignment Error on Child Model Update

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, mass-assignment

I'm having problems with updating a child model via nested form. I've read many threads on StackOverflow in hope to finding a solution but no luck there. adding :contact_info_attributes to service's attr_accessible doesn't do anything to remedy this problem.

Here's the form.

```
<% form_for(@service)  do |service| %>
<%= fields_for :contact_info do |c| %>
<p>
  Contact Person: <%= c.text_field :contactPerson %>
</p>
<p>
  Contact Number: <%= c.text_field :contactNumber %>
</p>
<% end %>
<p>
  Issue: <%= service.text_field :issue, :rows => 3 %>
</p>
<p>
  Urgency: <%= service.text_field :urgency %>
</p>
<%= submit_tag "Update" %> 
<% end %>
```

Here's my contact_info model.

```
class ContactInfo < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :services

  attr_accessible :contactPerson, :contactNumber
end
```

Here's my service model.

```
 class Service < ActiveRecord::Base
 belongs_to :user

 has_one :contact_info
 accepts_nested_attributes_for :contact_info, :allow_destroy => true

 attr_accessible :issue, :urgency, :contact_info_attributes, :group, :member

 end
```

Here is the 'update' action.

```
# services_controller.rb

def update
  @service = Service.find(params[:id])
  if @service.update_attributes(params[:service]) && @service.update_attributes(params[:contact_info])
   redirect_to service_path(@service) 
  else
    redirect_to edit
  end
end
```

Everytime I try to update the form, the service part of the form goes through okay, but :contact_info keeps running into mass assignment error like so.

```
Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"ykJt08tkHSzoYgyQu11lnKms1BZ+vM2i/Q0ZOoYDxks=", "contact_info"=>{"contactPerson"=>"Jmes Jor", "contactNumber"=>"3726262"}, "service"=>{"issue"=>"My house is flooded.", "urgency"=>"1"}, "commit"=>"Update", "id"=>"46"}
Service Load (0.8ms)  SELECT "services".* FROM "services" WHERE "services"."id" = 46 LIMIT 1
WARNING: Can't mass-assign protected attributes: contactPerson, contactNumber
```

Help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your forms are not nested.

Instead of:

```
<%= fields_for :contact_info do |c| %>
```

Put:

```
<%= service.fields_for :contact_info do |c| %>
```